# 1997 Pathfinder - cranks won't start

Tags: nissan, cranks-wont-run, pathfinder

Couple weeks ago my Pathfinder would occasionally lose RPM's at idle and sometimes die but started right back up. Then it began dying while driving regardless of speed - RPM would drop to nothing, car would die but would start back up. Yesterday it did this many times and then finally just refused to start anymore. Plenty of fuel. Put in a new distributor, spark plugs and plug wires. Fuel pump and filter only a year old.No clogs, etc. Checked spark, getting plenty. Checked fuel pressure, fine. Any more ideas? ... thanks

Comment: Are there any codes stored?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: awhile back I was getting codes for both O2 sensors, that's it

Comment: also checked for blown head gasket - fine
checked for slipped or broken timing belt - fine
verified the security system wasn't interfering - fine

The only thing I can think left to try is a new crank sensor

Comment: how did you check for blown head gasket? did you do a compression check on all cylinders ? did you check for spark on all wires? has the catalytic converter ever been changed?

Comment: head gasket - just the simple standards, checked condition of oil and compression check. No indication it is a problem.
did not check compression on all cylinders, checked 3.
did not check for spark on all all wires, checked 3.
The cats test fine, they were changed 100K ago.

Answer (score 0):

There are two test that I can think of. Injectors and timing.

Injectors are the easy test. The best way is to listen to the injector with a stethoscope while cranking. You will hear a knocking sound if the injector is firing. The second best is to use a noid light or equivalent. If the light is flashing then the injector is firing. This is not as good because the noid light is a very light load compared to the injector and may show a false positive if the injector driver is weak.

The timing check is a bit more challenging. Remove a spark plug and install a compression gauge tube. Don't connect the actual gauge to the tube quick connect. Then install a spark tester on the spark plug wire of the same cylinder. Place your thumb over the tube and watch the spark tester while cranking. The puff under your thumb and the spark should be at **exactly** the same time. If they are not then there is a timing problem. This may not be a timing belt issue, it may be a flex plate issue.

PS if the vehicle is sparking then most likely the crank sensor is ok.

Comment: Timing is correct at 15 degrees BTDC
Getting plenty of spark, getting plenty of fuel
Replaced the main reply switch today on suggestion....nothing.

Comment: @sam Did you perform both tests as suggested?